# How to correctly use file content with virtual path using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have an AngularJs app (v1) that is built as a Docker image (with Nginx as webserver). It has below structure

```
-app
  --build
    --js
      |-app.min.js
      |-login.min.js
    --styles
      |-app.min.css
      |-login.min.css
  --assets
    --images
    --fonts
  --index.html
  --login.html
```

I have the following **nginx config**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location /content {
    rewrite ^/content$ /index.html;
  }

  location /content/login {
    rewrite ^/content/login$ /login.html;
  }

}
```

This is **index.html** file

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
  <header>
    <script src="build/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles/app.min.css">
  </header>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

and **login.html** file

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app-login">
  <header>
    <script src="build/js/login.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles/login.min.css">
  </header>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**What I want to achieve**

When users go to `http://localhost:3000/content` the app will serve `index.html` and `login.html` if users visit `http://localhost:3000/content/login`.

Both of `/content` and `/content/login` are routes that don't exsit on the Angularjs app.

**What did I get**

When accessing `http://localhost:3000/content/login` the app loaded 2 following files

- `http://localhost:3000/content/build/js/login.min.js`
- `http://localhost:3000/content/build/styles/login.min.css`

Both of them got 404 error code.

**What did I expect**

I want Nginx to serve directly the file `http://localhost:3000/content/build/js/login.min.js` with content of file from `http://localhost:3000/build/js/login.min.js`. It also apply for CSS files.

Comment: When you run `http://localhost:3000/` you will not hit nginx, because nginx is listening on port 80.

Comment: @jb_alvarado Ah I am using docker-compose to listen port 80 from nginx then exporting it to port 3000 on my host machine.